# How to create new missing rows and interpolate values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
utc_timestamp               feed    data
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   A       1
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   A       5
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   B       6
2015-10-13 16:00:00+00:00   A       10
2015-10-13 17:00:00+00:00   A       11
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   B       11
```

I need to group by `feed`, sort by `utc_timestamp` and identify cases when the timestamps divided by a gap of more than 1 hour.

For example, let's take a look at rows when `feed` is equal to `A`. Between `2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00` and `2015-10-13 16:00:00+00:00` there is a gap of 4 hours.

```
utc_timestamp               feed    data
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   A       1
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   A       5
2015-10-13 16:00:00+00:00   A       10
2015-10-13 17:00:00+00:00   A       11
```

I need to interpolate the missing hours to get something like this:

```
utc_timestamp               feed    data
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   A       1
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   A       5
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   A       6
2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   A       7
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   A       8
2015-10-13 16:00:00+00:00   A       10
2015-10-13 17:00:00+00:00   A       11
```

The interpolation method is not so important. It can be a linear interpolation or just the filling of a gap with equal numbers. For example, if the `data` gap is (10 - 5 => 5) and the gap is 4 hours, then each new row can just have the value of `5/4`.

Is there any way to automate this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working first add not exist rows by [`Resampler.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.asfreq.html) and then interpolate per groups in lambda function:

```
df['utc_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['utc_timestamp'])


df = (df.set_index('utc_timestamp')
        .groupby('feed')['data']
        .resample('H')
        .asfreq()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  feed             utc_timestamp   data
0    A 2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   1.00
1    A 2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   5.00
2    A 2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   6.25
3    A 2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   7.50
4    A 2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   8.75
5    A 2015-10-13 16:00:00+00:00  10.00
6    A 2015-10-13 17:00:00+00:00  11.00
7    B 2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   6.00
8    B 2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   8.50
9    B 2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00  11.00
```

Another solution with lambda function:

```
df = (df.set_index('utc_timestamp')
        .groupby('feed')['data']
        .apply(lambda x: x.resample('H').asfreq().interpolate())
        .reset_index())
```